# how to find unity 3d models?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, 3d-modelling

For learning purposes, I'm trying to make a 3d version out of Arkanoid, and it's basically like the pic below. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the different bat shapes.

The way we did it in 2D was simple:

1. Make a different picture in Gimp
2. edit the polygon collider2D so that it fits

But since it's a 3D remade version I'm doing, I have to get some special 3D models, which are meant to:

1. the surface facing the screen should have interesting shapes
2. Every point of the sides should be a straight line towards the bottom.

What is the best way to get it?

1. Online assets? If so , can you show me some search key words to search for it?
2. Learn Maya? Is it hard to learn?
3. (*^*^(*&())
   [Game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEye2.png)

Comment: Well I think best way will be to make them in Blender or Maya. For simple shapes this is not very hard to do but still will need some patience.

Comment: usually the fastest and cheapest way is to buy your assets.

Comment: You can use any 3d model website like cgtrader or tf3dm. Make the search for fbx and free. You will have to go through a few of them as all assets are not meant to be for games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just too many websites for online purchase of unity assets. So you need to search for yourself. here are the keywords which work best for unity assets:

**For 2D assets:** Sprite | Transparent PNG

**For 2D animations:** Spritesheet

**For 3D assets:** 3D Model | 3D Unity Asset

**For 3D animated models:** 3D Model With Unity Animation | 3D Model With mecanim

This link has many websites:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16650/game-asset-website-list-free-and-paid-textures-mod.html

This asset provides many animations:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/6444

Sometimes searching for a complete project or a full pack is a good idea. E.g. *Animals Pack Unity* or *Unity Military Pack*

Comment: The best answer ever! Thanks.